# MapKit : add MKPolyline hide MKTileOverlay

Tags: objective-c, mkpolyline, mktileoverlay

I have a `MKMapView` working with a `MKTileOverlay` showing tiles from a local database. It's working fine.
Then I used `MKDirections` to get direction between two coordinates and draw the route like that :

```
MKRoute *route = response.routes.lastObject;
MKPolyline *polyline = route.polyline;

// Draw path on overlay
[self.mapView insertOverlay:polyline aboveOverlay:self.tileOverlay];
```

But when I zoom to see the line, it appears without the tile background (normaly loaded from `MKTileOverlay` (stored into `self.tileOverlay`)). I joined an image to see better.

I also made this code to render overlays :

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKTileOverlay class]]) {
        return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];
    }
    else if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *lineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        lineView.lineWidth = 3;
        return lineView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

It's like the "tile" that render the line hide the tile loaded from the `MKTileOverlay`. How can I :
- specify that I the `MKPolyline` overlay must be transparent ?
- reload the background tile ?

Screeshot :

[See the tile with line has no background anymore http://sigmanet.ch/tmp/screen.png](http://sigmanet.ch/tmp/screen.png)

Answer (score 5):

After days of work, here is my own solution.

Extend `MKPolylineRenderer` and add a reference to the `MKTileOverlayRenderer`. Let's call this new class `MCPolylineRenderer`.

In this class, override this two methods :

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    // Draw path only if tile render has a tile
    if ([self.tileRenderRef canDrawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale]) {
        [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
    }
}

- (BOOL)canDrawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale {
    // We can draw path only if tile render can also
    return [self.tileRenderRef canDrawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale];
}
```

Now, in the `mapView:renderedForOverlay` method, replace

```
MKPolylineRenderer *lineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
```

with

```
MCPolylineRenderer *lineView = [[MCPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
lineView.tileRenderRef = self.tileRender;
```

Also, you need to be sure that the `loadTileAtPath:result:` method doesn't result a tile when there is nothing to render (like a "tile not found" image).

This code will have effect that when there is no background tile to render, the path won't be draw neither.

Comment: This solution also works with ImageRenderer and TileRenderer. Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to subclass MKPolylineRenderer to synchronize renderers drawing abilities.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class MyPolylineRenderer: MKPolylineRenderer {

    var tileRenderer: MKTileOverlayRenderer?

    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        if (tileRenderer?.canDraw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale) ?? true) {
            super.draw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, in: context)
        }
    }

    override func canDraw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale) -> Bool {
        return tileRenderer?.canDraw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale) ?? super.canDraw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale)
    }
}
```

Then in your `MKMapViewDelegate`, keep a reference to your tileRenderer and implement the `rendererForOverlay` :

```
var tileRenderer: MKTileOverlayRenderer?

public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
        let lineRenderer = NXPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        lineRenderer.tileRenderer = tileRenderer
        // Configure your polyline overlay renderer here...
        return lineRenderer;
    }

    if let tileOverlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay {
        if tileRenderer == nil || tileRenderer.overlay != overlay {
            tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }
        return tileRenderer
    }

    return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}
```

All credits for the idea goes to @Jonathan, I'm just posting a swift ready to copy/paste code for newcomers.

Comment: in my case the Polygons and Polylines vanishes after the tile loads. How Do I solve this issue?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale When you add a Polyline or Polygon, you can choose it's level (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkoverlaylevel?language=swift)

You can also tweak the Z level of your overlays (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452575-exchangeoverlayatindex?changes_6)

Hope you'll find useful info there.